# Nuget add packages gives access denied errors

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

When I add Nuget packages via the Visual Studio 2015 GUI some packages don't install with the following error

> Access to the path 'Microsoft.DotNet.InternalAbstractions.dll' is denied.

I tried running Visual Studio 2015 as Administrator  and uninstalling the packages and adding them again but I still get the same error

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I closed Visual Studio and killed the 2 running  processes called dotnet as well as deleted the C:\Users\myser.nuget\packages folder to ensure all packages are redownloaded again in case something was corrupt.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer here. Please mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Comment: Infinite thanks, Sir ! Glad you answered your own question.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the dll path and make sure to give the right permission access to the local machine :

I usually do the below :

1- Untick the Read-only field :

[image]

2- Add the missing user access :

[image]

Comment: I also had to untick the 'Hidden' in order for it to work.

Comment: Good luck if the dll path is not there.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because I have cleared the NuGet cache.

I did the oldest trick in the book. I restarted my PC and then I was able to restore packages

Answer (score 0):

I close my Visual Studio.. and start it again as an administrator... It Worked.

Comment: And from then on you could use it as normal user? Or are you recommending to always run as an administrator? That would seem of questionable wisdom to me, especially becaue it seems from other answers that the solution is possible on configuration level.