# Access denied error when update/restore NuGet packages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have created cross-platform `Xamarin Forms` project and right after that I try to update or restore packages, but I am getting this error:

> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages:
>  Access to the path 'Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll' is denied.

I am running Visual Studio 2017 Community as admin and the `NuGet` cache is cleared every time before start to update/restore packages.

Comment: Try to clean the nuget cache.

Comment: I tried many times (every time when try to update).

Comment: Maybe try deleting all `obj` and `bin` folders in all of your project folders, move the solution to the root of your C drive (just to make sure), and run VS as an admin. If that does not work, I would suggest removing all references to the NuGet that needs restoring and install it again like new.

Comment: I had the same problem. I did this. I removed all nuget package and clean solution. After clean i went compiling all project one by one. For me this solved. Anybody say me to take care when update the nuget packages.

Comment: I even cannot access the folder. For the example: `'C:\Users\Masterbyter\.nuget\packages\xamarin.android.support.animated.vector.drawable\25.4.0.2\lib\MonoAndroid70'`, via file explorer. Now I am searching ways to do that, because for the parent folder all the accounts are with full permissions (including child objects/folders/files), except special permissions. I am trying and to make it not `read-only`, but access is denied, too.

Comment: Start PC and Try Again.

Comment: Close all the apps that can use NuGet (LinqPad for example). Solved problem for me.

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951949/nuget-add-packages-gives-access-denied-errors

Comment: If rebooting PC doesn't allow you to modify/empty the folder, and you are administrator account, then google `windows disable startup programs` - something is locking the folder. You need to start windows without whatever-it-is running. Easiest way is to disable ALL startup tasks; start in safe mode.

Answer (score 4):

Doing a restart fixed it for me

Comment: Error went away after rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem "Access to the path '....dll' is denied." here for a TeamCity build during Nuget Restoration and on dependency `Microsoft.Data.Entity.Build.Tasks.dll`.

Lost a long time to do things like :

- Clearing entire working copy,
- Cleaning Nuget cache using command line "nuget locals all -clear",
- Manually checking for locked files on appropriate folders using tools like LockHunter...

Nothing worked.
Until a reboot, which was not my favorite solution because it happened on a server that hosts a lot of other things.

But the error came back a short time after (only one or two builds later. I believe the read only attribute TeamCity puts on its working copy has something to do with this).

**I found the real cause in my case** :

Some old .csproj contained calls to nuget to ensure it's installed and enabled. This is not useful anymore since nuget has became a native tools, and it can lead to errors !
So in .csproj, remove lines like :

```
      <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets" Condition="Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" />
      <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>Ce projet fait référence à des packages NuGet qui sont manquants sur cet ordinateur. Utilisez l'option de restauration des packages NuGet pour les télécharger. Pour plus d'informations, consultez http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. Le fichier manquant est : {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\....props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\.....props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\....targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\....targets'))" />
     </Target>
```

And let nuget do his job as it wants.

Those are only examples of problematic lines, of courses your may differ.